# App Provisioning Profile XC:?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I am submitting a new version of my app to the apple app store and noticed there are now two distribution provisioning files.  One starts with XC:?  What is this XC: provisioning file and is this the one i use now and or how do i know?

Answer (score 7):

XC: means that the provisioning profile was automatically generated by xCode.
If you don't trust xCode, then create the profile manually from developer.apple and select your profile when archiving the app.